# Spring security authentication - looks like infinity loop but it works. How?

Tags: spring-security

how does it really works?
I wrote a sample app using spring boot with security and thymeleaf.
As [tutorial]: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springsecurity.html shows ones just need to create controller and login page. But...

In security config there is fragment as

```
    loginPage("/login.html")
```

then in controller there is request mapping for /login like

```
    @RequestMapping("/login.html")
       public String login() {
       return "login.html";
    }
```

and then in thymeleaf page there is action mapping like

```
    <form th:action="@{/login.html}" method="post">
```

So..when ones try to access restricted page is redirected to login page which means that login.html is displayed. Then after filling the form user clicks the button and trigger action which is mapped on controller that returns login.html once again. Looks like a loop. But it works. How??

Comment: Show us the rest of the `login.html` source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see the confusion here. In recent versions of Spring Security, it is possible and even encouraged by default that the *login page* and *login processing URL* are the same address (but they don't need to be). This is possible because of different HTTP methods.

- When redirected to login page, the page is retrieved using a GET request. The authentication filter sees this, but passes on the request to Spring MVC and the controller, since it is a GET request.
- When submitting the form, the username and password are sent in a POST request. The authentication filter intercepts this request since it is POST, performs the authentication and takes action depending on the result. The request is not forwarded to the controller in this case.